# Progress report for spark.ml.gradientboosting?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm using spark.ml gradient boosting. It takes almost one day to generate results. Is there a way to display progress? (for instance, how many trees have been generated so far)

Comment: Unfortunately, no beside generally what's the progress of a regular task which you can check in the spark web UI.

Answer (score 0):

Set the default log level to "DEBUG" in the log4j.properties file or by modifying the Spark context in the shell `spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("DEBUG")`. This will provide debug messages with status updates on tree building, e.g.

```
[DEBUG] 2016-07-31 11:36:23,689 org.apache.spark.ml.tree.impl.GradientBoostedTrees logDebug - ###################################################
[DEBUG] 2016-07-31 11:36:23,690 org.apache.spark.ml.tree.impl.GradientBoostedTrees logDebug - Gradient boosting tree iteration 2
[DEBUG] 2016-07-31 11:36:23,690 org.apache.spark.ml.tree.impl.GradientBoostedTrees logDebug - ###################################################
```

Debug logging information will also show you the error of the GBT on each iteration as well.

Comment: Thanks Seth. I'm using Ipython (pyspark) on Spark Standalone. I've done sc.setLogLevel("DEBUG") on my notebook, but I still don't see any DEBUG messages in my logs.

Answer (score 0):

This does the job quite nicely
--conf spark.ui.showConsoleProgress=true